# im getting user not found when trying to send an OTP email on the frontend, but it works on Insomnia

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I am creating an OTP function to reset password which works via insomnia, when trying to connect this to the frontend its not working, i keep getting the error user not found from the verifyuser function. I think its because it queries the email and the email has a %40 instead of the @ sign in the query. I'm not sure if thats the case but wondering if there's a way to get around this. I am verifying the user so the OTP is tied to their account.

Below are my functions, I haven't even tested the verifyotp and resetpassword on the client side yet since i hit a roadblock on the generateotp part

Another thing, for some reason my email address doesn't seem to work via the .env file but every other env variable does

```
export const verifyUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try { 
        const { email } = req.method == "GET" ? req.query : req.body;

        // check the user existance
        const exist = await User.findOne({ email });
        if(!exist) return res.status(404).send({ error : "Can't find User!"});
        next();

    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(404).send({ error: "Authentication Error"});
    }
}


export const generateOTP = async (req, res) => {
    const {email} = req.body
    try {
    req.app.locals.OTP = await otpGenerator.generate(6, {lowerCaseAlphabets: false, upperCaseAlphabets: false, specialChars: false})
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
    let config =  {
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: 'email@gmail.com',
    pass: process.env.PASS,
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
    }
}

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config)

    let message = {
        from: process.env.USER,
        to: email,
        subject: "Reset your password",
        text: `Your OTP is ${req.app.locals.OTP}`,
        html: `<b>Your OTP is ${req.app.locals.OTP}</b>`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(message).then(
        (info)=> {return res.status(201).json({
        msg: 'Message sent successfully!', 
        info: info.messageId, 
        preview: nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info)})}
        );      
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
}

export const verifyOTP = async (req, res) => {
    const {code} = req.query;
    if(parseInt(req.app.locals.OTP) === parseInt(code)){
        req.app.locals.OTP = null // reset otp value
        req.app.locals.resetSession = true // start session for reset password
        return res.status(201).send({msg: 'Verified OTP'})
    }
    return res.status(400).send({error: 'Invalid OTP'})
}

export const createResetSession = async (req,res) =>{
    if (req.app.locals.resetSession){
        req.app.locals.resetSession = false // allow access to this route only once
        return res.status(201).send({msg:'Access granted'})
    }
    return res.status(440).send({error: 'Session expired'})
}

export async function resetPassword(req,res){
    try {       
        if(!req.app.locals.resetSession) return res.status(440).send({error : "Session expired!"});
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({email})
        if (!user) {return res.status(404).send({error : "User not Found"})}
        const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 5)
        await User.updateOne({ email:user.email },{ $set: {password: hashedPassword}})
                return res.status(201).send({ msg : "Password Updated...!"})
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send({ error })
    }
}
```

here are my routes

```
router.post("/login", login)
router.post("/logout", logout)
router.get('/generateOTP',verifyUser,localVariables, generateOTP)
router.get('/verifyOTP',verifyUser,verifyOTP)
router.get('/createResetSession',createResetSession)
router.put('/resetPassword',verifyUser, resetPassword)
```